# Iframe not filling whole div on IE9

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with a header div and an iframe used to display a map in the rest of the page, resizing to the maximum space it can under the header div.

I can get the method working on Firefox and Chome, but the iframe won't fill the div on IE9. Anyone know what the issue is? Rather than post html, here's a few links to the problem page and the old page I'm re-designing that does work in the same way in IE9.

New problem page (doesn't resize div in IE9):
http://permitmap.paydirt.co.nz/devtest/permitmap.html

Old page using the same technique that does work in IE9:
http://permitmap.paydirt.co.nz/

It might be my abuse of [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? I use bootstrap it as it's meant to be used on normal content pages, but this page is a one-off that needs to display a map in as much of the page as possible while still following the styling for the header as the rest of the site.

And my use of tables for layout is also bad practice I know, but it's the only method I've found to achieve the desired effect with the iframe (believe me, I've tried a lot of ideas out that don't use tables!).

Thanks in advance any CSS / HTML gurus out there that can help!

How much time is lost making IE behave like other browsers!? Microsoft must cost the planet an incredible amount in lost man hours and extra expense supporting IE.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, just noticed I had to solve this issue with the original page.

Removing the DOCTYPE element from the top of the page resolves the issue in IE9!